# ng-click not working on <li> element

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to insert ng-click on my list. But it doesn't work. I have tried using both ng-repeat and without ng-repeat on li elements.

The HTML code is:

```
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#" ng-click="changeRoute()">Home</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Products</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Customer Feedback</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

And here is the controller:

```
 $scope.changeRoute = function() {
     console.log('Test');
 }
```

Comment: try removing the href attribute from the a tag. Even i faced similar once and removing the href fixed the issue and also make sure the li element falls inside the scope of controller.

Comment: It works fine, both in the `<li>` and in the `<a>`. https://plnkr.co/edit/u2llrRsagTXdOLvZNxP2

Comment: @SatejS I think he wants to dynamically add the `ng-click` functions to all the `li`s using ng-repeat for some reason...

Comment: @SatejS I am using bootstrap navbar in this. Do you think it is bootstrap compatibility issue?

Comment: @alyson_216,what exactly is the issue you are facing?The link is pretty much your code.

Comment: This navbar is a component used from bootstrap. If you add the bootstrap library, you will see the same code doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this if you really wanted.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#" ng-click="changeRoute('Home')">Home</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#" ng-click="changeRoute('About Us')">About Us</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#" ng-click="changeRoute('Products')">Products</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#" ng-click="changeRoute('Customer Feedback')">Customer Feedback</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#" ng-click="changeRoute('Contact Us')">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>

 $scope.changeRoute = function(route) {
     //handle route here
 }
```

But whats wrong with just putting the links in the `href`s, no `ng-repeat` required?

Comment: When you use double quotes inside of double quotes, you need to escape them.

Comment: I am trying to change the route on ng-click. But it doesn't seems to work. I have tried with ng-repeat. But same problem is there.

Comment: @Wowsk, i am not using double quotes, but it doesn't seems to work.

Comment: @Wowsk changed to single quotes

Comment: @AlexLogan make sure you change the about us double quotes too.

Comment: @alyson_216 I was telling the answerer about the double quotes, not you.